# Trait bound Serialize is not satisfied even though the type has derive(Serialize)

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm trying to serialize JSON using serde macros but I only get this error:

```
src/models/pulse.rs:89:28: 89:49 error: the trait bound `models::pulse::Pulse: serde::ser::Serialize` is not satisfied [E0277]
src/models/pulse.rs:89      if let Ok(bulk_string) = serde_json::to_string(&self) {
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/models/pulse.rs:89:28: 89:49 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
src/models/pulse.rs:89:28: 89:49 note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `serde::ser::Serialize` for `&mut models::pulse::Pulse`
src/models/pulse.rs:89:28: 89:49 note: required by `serde_json::to_string`
```

I don't seem to have anything wrong in the code.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Pulse {
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if="Option::is_none")]
    id: Option<u64>,

    #[serde(skip_serializing_if="Option::is_none")]
    category: Option<i64>,

    #[serde(skip_serializing_if="Option::is_none")]
    title: Option<String>,

}
```

Is it an dependency error? Or is the something wrong with my code? I use

```
[dependencies.serde]
git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde.git"
[dependencies.serde_macros]
git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/serde.git"
[dependencies.serde_json]
git = "https://github.com/serde-rs/json.git"
```

I got a question why I use git dependencies. The reason is that I get:

```
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-

0.18.0/src/mac.rs:6:5: 6:39 error: unresolved import `syntax::feature_gate::GatedCfgAttr`. There is no `GatedCfgAttr` in `syntax::feature_gate`. Did you mean to use `GatedCfg`? [E0432]
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:6 use syntax::feature_gate::GatedCfgAttr;
                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:6:5: 6:39 help: run `rustc --explain E0432` to see a detailed explanation
   Compiling num-traits v0.1.32
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:113:18: 113:81 error: this function takes 4 parameters but 5 parameters were supplied [E0061]
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:113     let mut cx = ExtCtxt::new(sess, cfg, ecfg, feature_gated_cfgs, macro_loader);
                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:113:18: 113:81 help: run `rustc --explain E0061` to see a detailed explanation
/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/aster-0.18.0/src/mac.rs:113:18: 113:81 note: the following parameter types were expected: &syntax::parse::ParseSess, std::vec::Vec<syntax::ptr::P<syntax::codemap::Spanned<syntax::ast::MetaItemKind>>>, syntax::ext::expand::ExpansionConfig<'_>, &mut syntax::ext::base::MacroLoader
```

I think the problem could be that you need to use nightly.

Comment: why are you using `git` dependencies? you should be using them through crates.io.

Comment: Because if I use crate: I get another error. @ker I have now updated the question.

Comment: run `cargo update` (the issue you are seeing was fixed yesterday, and only occurs on nightly) or use the stable compiler

Answer (score 2):

As of `rustc 1.20.0-nightly`, `serde 1.0.11` and `serde-json 1.0.2`, this code compiles without a problem.

On a side note, you really should use crates.io dependencies instead of git ones.